# Are auxiliary fuel tanks still an option?

Tags: honda, fuel-tank

My 2014 Honda pilot gets about 20MPG, but when I am towing the camp trailer that falls to between 10 and 13MPG.  I have seen a couple different values as to the actual fuel tank capacity, in real life I think about 17 gallons is the most it has taken to fill it up.

In a trip across the US, this means I need to stop for fuel about every 120 miles. (*in parts of the country it can be very far between gas stations*)

Back in the era of mechanical fuel pumps and carburetors, we would add a second fuel tank to pickups and SUV's, there was a valve on the floor, that we turned to switch between fuel tanks.

Searching Google for an auxiliary fuel tank for a 2014 pilot, is not finding me what I want.

Are auxiliary fuel tanks still an option for modern SUVs?

Comment: I said fuel, but this is specific gasoline.

Comment: A quick search finds lots of options for pickup trucks, but those are meant to be installed in the bed. For your SUV, the tank would have to be placed in the passenger compartment (trunk), which would complicate matters (fumes inside). You could also look into fuel tanks for race cars.

Comment: universal fuel tanks: http://www.tanksinc.com/index.cfm/page/ptype=results/category_id=133/mode=cat/cat133.htm

Comment: @Hobbes many newer cars get upset if the filler cap is not tight on the one original equipment gas tank.  How would the computer handle a second tank? Also as you eluded to in your first comment, the under carriage of newer SUVs is more tightly sculptured, they may not be safe/legal place to install a second tank.

Comment: @JamesJenkins so you have just answered your own question.... "may not be safe/legal place to install a second tank"

Comment: @SolarMike I am just guessing.

Comment: it's not written as a guess...

Comment: Consider carrying extra fuel - even on the trailer (depends on law / location / country etc) and manually topping up as necessary.